# python programming... recoding each element in a list based on conditional logic test

Tags: python, list

I have a python related question. 
Given a list like this one: `mylist=[21,35,38,41,10,9]`
how can i write the code to create a new list that performs some conditional logic on each element of mylist. The logic I want to apply is based on this intuition:

`if mylist[i] < mylist[i+1] then 1 else 0`.

So in this case the recoded list would look like:

```
re_code=[1,1,1,0,0] (yes len(re_code) = len (mylist) - 1)
```

I then would like to extract the indices of the elements with 0 if that is possible. So a list like this= `index=[4,5]`. I hope the way I explained this makes sense.

I tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
for i in mylist:
    re_code=[i for i in mylist]
    re_code[i]=[1 if mylist[i]< mylist[i +1] else  0]
    return(re_code)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pythonic way to do this is to use `zip` with a list comprehensions, which avoids using the indices at all to get `re_code`, then `enumerate` to get the indices again for `index`.

```
mylist=[21,35,38,41,10,9]

re_code = [int(a < b) for a, b in zip(mylist, mylist[1:])]
index = [i for i, v in enumerate(re_code) if v == 0]

print(re_code)
print(index)
```

The printout from that is

```
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[3, 4]
```

If you just want the value of `index` and do not need `re_code` that could be done in just one list comprehension. Ask if you want me to show it.

The `zip` pairs up consecutive items in the list. If the list is very long or if it could be an iterable rather than a list, you should use `pairwise` recipe from the [itertools documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html) rather than the `zip`.

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list-comprehension:

```
mylist = [21,35,38,41,10,9]

re_code = [int(mylist[i] < mylist[i+1]) for i in range(len(mylist) - 1)]

print(re_code) # ==> [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost there just a couple of points.

It might be easier to iterate over the list using an index, rather than accessing an element at a time, so something like:

```
for i in range(len(mylist) - 1):  # notice we iterate up to the second to last element
```

And you can then access the list using `i` as the index inside the loop, e.g. `mylist[i]`.

Currently, `for i in mylist` will give you the actual elements rather than their index.

Finally, you probably want to keep track of the indices, so just store `i` in a list for that purpose.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe for a beginner it might be easier to understand a simple `for-loop`?

```
mylist = [21,35,38,41,10,9]
iterlist = iter(mylist[1:]) # create an iterator from your list minus first element
result = []

for i in mylist:
    try:
        if i < next(iterlist): # compare current val with val in front of it
            result.append(1)
        else:
            result.append(0)
    except StopIteration: # if there's nothing left in the iterator end the loop
        break

print(result)

[1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```